# matplotlib: how to change yticklabel size for log scale?

Tags: matplotlib, logarithm

I want to increase the font size of the `yticklabels` and also want to make them bold. I am using a log scale for the Y-axis. I get only the first yticklabel in large size and others are small. Following is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6),dpi=100)
ax1.plot([10, 100, 1000], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Please help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strange behavior...

However, it is still possible to get the expected result by changing the `ytick` configuration, in the beginning of the code, with this line:

```
matplotlib.rc('ytick', labelsize=20)
```

You may also change the color too for the labels:

```
matplotlib.rc('ytick', labelsize=20, labelcolor='red')
```

But, a change on font weight will apply to both axes, using the code:

```
matplotlib.rc('font', weight='bold')
```

There are more options listed on the official documentation:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/customize_rc.html

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rcParams

Comment: thank you for the answer. It helped to increase the y-axis labelsize for all of them. But I want to bold only the yticklabels and not xticklabels.

Answer (score 0):

With logarithmic axes, the ticks for each order of magnitude (`10^x`) are considered *major* while the ticks between (`X \times 10^x`) are considered *minor*. So, you can apply formatting to each separately with the `which` argument, or to both with `which='both'` like so:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6),dpi=100)
ax1.plot([10, 100, 1000], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

---

```py
ax1.tick_params(axis = 'y', which = 'both', labelsize = 20)
```

---

```py
plt.show()
```